# Error when clicking item from listview

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, uri, android-videoview

Could someone tell me why i am not able to pass the choice or even toast when choosing an item from this list view.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(List<uploadedContentModels> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (result != null) {
            VidAddressAdapter adapter = new VidAddressAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.rowv_vid, result);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String choice = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), choice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 //                 Uri video = Uri.parse(clickedAddress);
 //                 videoView.setVideoURI(video);
 //                 videoView.start();
                }
            });
```

The error i am getting is;

```
  04-03 18:31:00.844 24899-24899/net.we4x4.we4x4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: net.we4x4.we4x4, PID: 24899
                                                             java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                 at net.we4x4.we4x4.MyUploadedVideos$JsonTask$1.onItemClick(MyUploadedVideos.java:185)
                                                                 at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:302)
                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1196)
                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3054)
                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3812)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

in the main activity i have a list view that get populated by JsonArray - Video clips addresses, which when one of them clicked it should be passed to the VideoView. i am unable to do that as you could see i commented that part of the code, because i got an error trying to pars the address to a uri, and when i tried to just Toast the choice i got also an Error. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here getName() is your PogoClass Item name with getter and setter,change this according to your getter setter item name

```
String choice = result.get(position).getName();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), choice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error said : `android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`. That simply means you're trying to cast two different classes, you should cast to the right type : `((MyClass)view)`
or get the item by position `result.get(position)`
`result` is your list of videos.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `listView` items are of type `LinearLayout`. Inside the `onItemClickListener` the `view` parameter represents your list item, so you're trying to cast a `LinearLayout` to a `TextView`. Perhaps you have a `TextView` inside the `LinearLayout` so to get it you need to call findViewById.

Use this

```
((TextView)((LinearLayout)view).findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id)).getText().toString();
```

instead of

```
((TextView)view).getText().toString();
```

to get the text from the `TextView`.

Comment: Dimitri Timofti, you are right, i was able to figure that out, @Amiti_Ranjan suggestion solved the problem, the i was able to Toast, and then pass it as a Uri to the VideoView, further on i will probably need to use your suggestion, which i am still waiting for answer to that post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370934/how-to-displaying-vid-thumbnail-in-listview-from-url